# Flash: can you play a video inside Stage3D?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, stage3d, starling-framework

I was wondering if it's possible to use a video (FLV, H264 or anything...) as a Texture for example?

I'm building 2D GPU accelerated game (with help of Starling Framework) and need to usea 45 sec long video as a background.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use StageVideo.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/stage_video.html

http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=134

Comment: I believe stage3d displays over stagevideo, so not sure this will work.

Comment: I'm gonna check that. But, that's only the part of the question. I'd like to know how could I use a video played on a face of a 3d model.

Comment: Take a look at this and see if it helps... http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/video-in-starling#post-5894